# Android - Connecting to backend server using public crt and private pem files

Tags: android, kotlin, ssl

I'm developing an app in which I have to communicate with backend server using certificate (in .crt file) and private key (.pem file).

The problem is - when I'm using curl, connection is successful

`curl (...) --cert pubcert.crt --key privkey.pem`

but when I'm trying to connect from Android app I'm getting

`HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

My OkHttpClient:

```
        val privKeyInputStream = context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.privkey)
        val pubKeyInputStream = context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.pubcert)

        val cf: CertificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
        val certificate: X509Certificate = cf.generateCertificate(pubKeyInputStream) as X509Certificate

        val keyPair = KeyPair(certificate.publicKey, loadPrivateKey(privKeyInputStream))

        val rootCertificate = HeldCertificate(keyPair, certificate)

        val certificates: HandshakeCertificates = HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
            .addTrustedCertificate(rootCertificate.certificate)
            .build()

        return OkHttpClient
            .Builder()
            .sslSocketFactory(certificates.sslSocketFactory(), certificates.trustManager)
            .build()
```

```
fun loadPrivateKey(inputStream: InputStream): PrivateKey? {
    var key: PrivateKey? = null
    try {
        val br = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
        val builder = StringBuilder()
        var inKey = false
        var line = br.readLine()
        while (line != null) {
            if (!inKey) {
                if (line.startsWith("-----BEGIN ") &&
                    line.endsWith(" PRIVATE KEY-----")
                ) {
                    inKey = true
                }
                line = br.readLine()
                continue
            } else {
                if (line.startsWith("-----END ") &&
                    line.endsWith(" PRIVATE KEY-----")
                ) {
                    inKey = false
                    break
                }
                builder.append(line)
            }
            line = br.readLine()
        }
        println(builder.toString())
        //
        val encoded: ByteArray = Base64.decode(builder.toString(), Base64.DEFAULT)
        val keySpec = PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded)
        val kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
        key = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec)
    } finally {
        inputStream.close()
    }
    return key
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution, I changed the HandshakeCertificates definition to:

```
val certificates: HandshakeCertificates = HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
            .addPlatformTrustedCertificates()
            .heldCertificate(HeldCertificate(keyPair, certificate))
            .build()
```

and now it works